# convert perl timestamp to human readable

Tags: perl, timestamp

I am reading a log file which contains time stamps which I want to convert to human readable.
In this command, $1 contains a time stamp (like this 1403457192.663):  $temp = localtime->mon($1) but instead of storing the month, $temp contains the same timestamp that was input.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. The time should be passed to the `localtime` function, not the `mon` method.:

```
$temp = localtime($1)->mon; # 6
```

You can use `strftime` with this to turn it into any arbitrary format

```
localtime($1)->strftime("%b %d %a"); # Jun 22 Sun
```

Or if you're not picky about the format you can just stringify it:

```
$temp = localtime($1);
print "$temp\n"; # Sun Jun 22 13:13:12 2014
```

This assumes that `Time::Piece` is loaded.

Comment: What about ye olde `strftime`?

Comment: I am using Time::localtime; ... which appears to work ... or should I use Time::Piece ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply go with

```
$ perl -E'
   use POSIX qw( strftime );
   say strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(1403457192.663));
'
2014/06/22 13:13:12
```

But you're using Time::localtime. That module overrides the `localtime` builtin, so you need a slight modification if you use that.

Either avoid using Time::localtime's `localtime`

```
$ perl -E'
   use POSIX           qw( strftime );
   use Time::localtime qw( localtime );
   say strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", CORE::localtime(1403457192.663));
'
2014/06/22 13:13:12
```

or flatten an existing Time::localtime object.

```
$ perl -E'
   use POSIX           qw( strftime );
   use Time::localtime qw( localtime );
   my $tm = localtime(1403457192.663);
   say strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", @$tm);
'
2014/06/22 13:13:12
```

All of these solutions lose the millisecond precision. If it's relevant, you'll have to extract it from the original input and reinsert it in the output.

Answer (score 0):

For formatting dates most system `strftime` manual pages will list a few "shortcuts" to get you certain "standard" formats.

*e.g.* `%F` is equivalent to `“%Y-%m-%d”`.

```
~/% perl -MPOSIX -E'say strftime"%D",localtime'
06/25/14
~/% perl -MPOSIX -E'say strftime"%F",localtime'
2014-06-25
```

These can make using "ye olde" `strftime` easier ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Perl since 5.10 now contains [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html). This makes it the *official* way to handle time in Perl. Or, about as *official* as something gets in Perl. Since it's always available, you might as well learn to use that:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;   # More time fun!

my $time = Time::Piece->new;   # Gets the current timestamp

my $month = $time->mon();          # Month from 1 to 12
my $month = $time->month();        # Abbreviation of the name of month
my $month = $time->fullmonth();    # Full name of the month
my $time = $time + (ONE_DAY * 30)  # Add thirty days to the time
my $date = $time->mdy              # The date 30 days from now.
```

Comment: The presence of a module in core does not imply a recommendation to use it. In fact, I strongly recommend against using Time::Seconds. It's extremely easy to use it incorrectly without realizing it because it forces you to write code that looks incorrect. (The number of seconds in a day is not constant.)